# Do you need an extra complement in sentences like these?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, complements

When I speak English, I fear I might be unconsciously relying on the syntax of my mother tongue a little too much, which might end up with me creating ungrammatical sentences (and even incomprehensible ones)

So for example, in sentences like these:

> You can criticize whatever you'd like without being so harsh.

> He was trying to help, you didn't need to be so harsh.

You can infer by context that both sentences are saying you shouldn't be harsh on said person/thing. However, for sentences like these to be grammatically right, do you need an extra complement? As in:

> You can criticize whatever you'd like without being so harsh **on it**

> He was only trying to help, you didn't need to be so harsh **on him**.

My question, to sum it up, is: *Do I need to put an extra complement for my sentence to be grammatically right, even if I already said it and you can infer it through context?*

Comment: Spelling; "syntax"

Answer (score 1):

For your first example, I'd use *about it*. Being *harsh on* would usually refer to harshness directed at a person, as in your second example. Otherwise, both examples are grammatical, and understandable given the right context.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the examples are fine with or also without the bolded phrases? (By the way, I’d say “be harsh *toward*” a person. Perhaps the choice of preposition depends on dialect.)

Comment: The examples are fine either with or without the bolded phrases. They don't even make the examples more specific - the object of the harshness is implied by the context.

Comment: I agree completely.